# null id generated for:class hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

all. So. I have a problem:

> null id generated for:class Notebook.Enities.Telephone

Yes, this problem has been to stackoverflow, but i'm here. Why? I arranged through the xml mapping.

**My Note.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="Notebook.Enities.Note" table="note" schema="notebase">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Id" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="telephoneId" class="Notebook.Enities.Telephone" cascade="save-update"/>
        <one-to-one class="Notebook.Enities.Description" name="descriptionId" cascade="save-update"/>
        <one-to-one class="Notebook.Enities.Human" name="humanId" cascade="save-update"/>
        <many-to-one class="Notebook.Enities.Group" name="group" fetch="join" lazy="false">
            <column name="Group" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Next, my Telephone.hbn.xml** (Telephone - phone for ru-lang.)

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="Notebook.Enities.Telephone" table="telephone" schema="notebase">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Id"/>
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">note</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="note" class="Notebook.Enities.Note" constrained="true"/>
        <property name="telephone" column="Telephone"/>
        <property name="descripton" column="Descripton"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**JSF-page Text.xhtml** (other objects all analogy Telephone)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>

<body>
<f:view>
    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
      <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputText value="Фамилия:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{human.family}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Имя:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{human.name}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Отчество:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{human.secondName}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Дата:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{human.birthday}">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Телефон:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{telephone.telephone}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Группа:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{group.group}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Описание:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{description.text}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton action="#{notebookFacade.createNote(human,telephone,group,description)}" value="Save" />
        <h:commandButton action="descriptionList" value="Cancel"/>
        <br/>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**And Method createNote();**

```
 public void createNote(Human human, Telephone telephone, Group group, Description description){
    Note note = new Note();
    note.setTelephoneId(telephone);
        telephone.setNote(note);
    note.setHumanId(human);
        human.setNote(note);
    note.setGroup(group);
    note.setDescriptionId(description);
        description.setNote(note);
    getNoteDAO.addNotes(note);
    System.out.println("Add work!");
}
```

**And addNotes();**

```
public void addNotes(Note note) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(note);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("This function is worked");
    session.close();
}
```

My scheme:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sjfu.jpg)

**If you need something else, please. And please help.**

Answer (score 0):

Following link is explain how to integrate hibernate relationship with xml configuration, so please look out it.

[Hibernate XML Mapping Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/)

Also you need to add *@Transactional* with *addNotes* service class method

```
@Transactional
public void addNotes(Note note) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(note);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("This function is worked");
    session.close();
}
```

Hope you will fix your problem!